# при установке контейнера в docker ловлю Error response from daemon

Tags: docker-compose, elasticsearch

прошу помощи. Столкнулся  с проблемой, когда при установке ELK через docker-compose в конце установки ловлю следующую ошибку:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container:
> failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create
> failed: unable to start container process: error during container
> init: error mounting
> "/run/desktop/mnt/host/d/Soft/elastic/configs/logstash/config.yml" to
> rootfs at "/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml": mount
> /run/desktop/mnt/host/d/Soft/elastic/configs/logstash/config.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
> (via /proc/self/fd/9), flags: 0x5001: not a directory: unknown: Are
> you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if
> the specified host path exists and is the expected type

Собственно, сам виновник:

```
     version: '3.7'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.8.1
    volumes:
      - ./configs/elasticsearch/config.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
      - ./docker_volumes/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: "elastic"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: "notapassword"
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

  logstash:
    image: logstash:8.8.1
    volumes:
      - ./configs/logstash/config.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    image: kibana:8.8.1
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./configs/kibana/config.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
    networks:
      - elk
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge
```